# How can I delete Time Machine backups of a particular file when that file is locked?

Tags: time-machine

I am trying to get rid of all backups of XCode.app in my Time Machine backup. When I enter Time Machine and select "Delete all Backups of XCode" in the context menu, it shows some deletion progress in the Finder and DesktopServiceHelper is busy for a moment until it displays the following error message:

> The operation can’t be completed because some items had to be skipped. For each item, choose File > Get Info, make sure “Locked” is deselected, and then check the Sharing & Permissions section. When you are sure the items are unlocked and not designated as Read Only or No Access, try again.

Any idea how this can be solved? I could only find one related thread on Google which didn't provide any helpful information.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't unlock said file?

Comment: I'm not sure it's safe to run such a command on the backup. Who knows what Time Machine uses these flags for?

Comment: Okay: what file is it that's locked that can't be deleted?

Comment: @JMY1000 I wished I knew. It must be some file in /Volumes/BackupHD/Backups.backupdb/Lastest/Applications/XCode.app.

Comment: I suspect it is in fact a bug in Time Machine. Why would the provided function for deleting backups be dysfunctional when the entire file system in Backups.backupdb is solely managed by Time Machine?

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't delete locked files to prevent you from deleting files you don't want to delete. Search for locked files using `find . -flags uchg`. You can then unlock them (either from the inspector window or by using the command `sudo find . -flags uchg -exec chflags nouchg {} \;`)

Comment: Again, I am using the command "Delete all Backups of …" which is provided by Time Machine. Why would that delete files I don't want to delete? I tried searching for `find . -flags uchg` in Volumes/BackupHD/Backups.backupdb/Lastest/Applications/XCode.app but it returned nil results.

Comment: Try doing it for your whole backup, it may not be in Xcode.app.